# Who is a boor בור?

Tags: words, hebrew, english

The Talmud frequently calls an individual a "boor".  Two examples:

*It has been reported: If one has learned Tanach and Mishnah but not Talmud, Rabbi Eleazar says he is an ignoramus [am ha-aretz]; Rabbi Shmuel ben Nahmani says he is a boor; Rabbi Yannai says he is a Samaritan [rejects sources beyond Torah]; Rabbi Aha ben Yaakov says he is a magician [who misleads others with illusions]. [Sotah 22a]*

*And one who recites the blessing on any of the mitzvot mentioned in the Torah may not answer 'amen' after himself; and if he does answer 'amen' he is a boor. [Berachot Y 58b]*

And what is the Hebrew for 'boor'?  Not, as you might expect, 'am haaretz', but rather...  **בור**  bet-vav-resh, vocalized BOOR!

Yet this is not the origin of the English word "boor".  The dictionary says:

Boor: noun:
1-a churlish, rude, or unmannerly person; 
2-a country bumpkin; rustic; yokel; 
3-peasant; 
4-Boer; Origin: 1545-55; Dutch boer; or Low German bur; (cognate with German Bauer -- farmer), derivative of Germanic to dwell, build, cultivate.

And what is the Arabic word for "boor"?  You guessed it -- it's "boor" **بور !**

Question:  Are the facts that the English "boor", the Hebrew **בור**  and the Arabic  بور sound identical and mean the same thing just a coincidence?

Comment: The fact that English boor comes from German *bur* doesn't rule out that if you continue tracing it back you'll get to Hebrew בור.

Comment: I'm really on the fence on this one. While the question does tie in the term to various Gemaras (and there's dozens others you can add to the list), ultimately the question is about an English word, asking if its etymology is from Hebrew. Is this on-topic? Is the fact that the potential ancestor is found in a Jewish text enough to make this Hebrew as pertains to Judaism?

Comment: Bor is an attribute of emptiness with onomatopoeia. The sound expresses resonance in a close empty litte place

Comment: I don't recall, offhand, which Mishnah in Pirkei Avot uses he term "boor". It will be a while before I can get to viewing it. If you find it, have a look at Rabbeinu Yonah's explanation (available in the back of a Gemarah Mas. Nezikin). I think he provides insight to exactly what the term means.

Comment: @DanF -- Pirkei Avot 2:5: אֵין בּוּר יְרֵא חֵטְא,  A boor cannot fear sin.  Bartenura: ""A boor (bur)  is empty of everything, and does not even know the nature of buying and selling; and he is worse than an ignorant person. "

Comment: @DanF -- Rabbenu Yonah: "The boor is empty - he does not have in him Torah or commandments or the way of the world in terms of good traits. And in the Targum (Onkelos Genesis 47:19), "do not place," is "do not tabur. And he did not need [to say], a boor cannot be pious, since he is not even one who fears sin - as from his emptiness, he does not [even] know to guard himself from sins."

Comment: I was quite certain he said something! Sounds like a close description of the English word. Esp. since he says that he does not have good traits and "the way of the world" (which seems to describe an "am ha'aretz". It seems that the boor is a superset of an am ha'aretz.)

Comment: If the question is only about the etymology and not about the meaning of the word in the mishna, you might want to ask on [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)